# JavaScript toLocaleString function does not return left zeros

Tags: javascript, date, format, locale, spanish

The problem is that the `toLocaleString` from Date prototype, in Spanish locale don't use 2-digit format when parsing dates with day/month only. The same problem with `toLocaleDateString`.

This is the problem, in Spanish locale (with en-US works fine):

```js
const dateObj = new Date(2023, 0, 1);
console.log(dateObj.toLocaleString("es-ES", {
  day: "2-digit",
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "2-digit"
}));
// Output: 01/01/23
console.log(dateObj.toLocaleString("es-ES", {
  day: "2-digit",
  month: "2-digit"
}));
// Output: 1/1
// Expected output: 01/01
```

Comment: According to [this document (in Spanish, from Spain)](https://www.rae.es/dpd/fecha) leading zeros on days and months are *not recommended* except when necessary for technical reasons. Personally I think it's weird that the JavaScript implementation works that way, but the last 10 minutes represent the sum total of research I've done into Spanish dates.

Comment: I would think that specifying the output of two digits would qualify as a "technical reason" to output two digits, including the leading zero...

Comment: Yea me too, also it's just good practice for anti-tampering purposes.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will parse the output, but it's weird that behavior.

Comment: what is by "e"?

Comment: The formatting produced by *toLocaleString* is not controlled by the ECMAScript standard (ECMA-262), but by the ECMAScript internationalization API specification (ECMA-402), which defers to the CLDR. Rules for Spanish are [here](https://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/v#/es/Gregorian/). You'll have to wade through ECMA-402 to work out the precedence of options and language ("es" is a BCP47 language tag, I have no idea why some standards call it a "locale", which is an entirely different concept).

Comment: BTW, *toLocaleString* is not a good way to format dates for precisely the reason in the OP: the format is controlled by rules such that the output may not be what you expect. If exact formatting is required, do it manually (a formatting library can help).

Comment: PS: If the language tag is changed to "es-mx" you'll get the desired result. ;-)